# JSON malformed how to correct

Tags: json

When I try and parse this json I get an error expecting number at http://jsoneditoronline.org/

```
[{"urltitle":"","urltypeid":"2,4,4,5,5","seriesname":"Census of State and Federal    Correctional 

Facilities","titleb":"Census of State and Federal Correctional Facilities, 1995","url":"\/content\/pub\/press

\/CSFCF95.PR,\/content\/pub\/pdf\/CSFC95EX.PDF,\/content\/pub\/pdf\/Csfcf95.pdf,\/content\/pub\/ascii

\/csfc95ex.txt,\/content\/pub\/ascii\/csfcf95.txt","releasedate":"1997-08-07 00:00:00.0","urltype":"Press Release 

","pubproductid":535,"title":"CENSUS OF STATE AND FEDERAL CORRECTIONAL FACILITIES, 1995","tagkeywords":""},

{"urltitle":"","urltypeid":"2,4,4,5,13","seriesname":"Indicators of School Crime and Safety","titleb":"Indicators 

of School Crime and Safety, 2000","url":"\/content\/pub\/press\/iscs00.pr,\/content\/pub\/pdf\/iscs00.pdf,

\/content\/pub\/pdf\/iscs00ex.pdf,\/content\/pub\/ascii\/iscs00.txt,\/content\/pub\/sheets

\/iscs00.zip","releasedate":"2000-10-26 00:00:00.0","urltype":"Press Release 

","pubproductid":992,"title":"INDICATORS OF SCHOOL CRIME AND SAFETY, 2000","tagkeywords":""}]
```

Comment: You don't "correct" bad json. You correct whatever generated the JSON in the first place.

Comment: I actually tested this on http://jsonlint.com/ and there are a number of issues with text being broken across multiple lines. You can't have this in the json and it needs to be corrected, like Marc B mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new line in a string constant:

```
 "seriesname": "Census of State and Federal    Correctional 

Facilities",
```

Should be:

```
 "seriesname": "Census of State and Federal    Correctional\n\nFacilities",
```

There are also several more of the same exact error.

Really, whatever created this JSON need to properly *escape* the data, including translating any carriage returns or line feeds to the appropriate escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks Guys, You were correct the spaces were killing the output. Can anyone recommend a tool that can cleanup the malformed json data? Got this data from an excel spreadsheet.